# using ggplot/facet_grid to make an ordered barplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, facet-grid

I'm trying to plot my data so that it looks something like this (taken from [this blog](https://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2013/08/14/how-do-i-re-arrange-ordering-a-plot-revisited/)):

[image: reordered by bar size]

My data looks like this:

```
head(Diet)
   Group      Category studies_n studies_pc
1  algae         algae        61       38.4
2  algae       biofilm         4        2.5
3  algae       diatoms         8        5.0
4  algae       fil alg        18       11.3
5  algae phytoplankton         2        1.3
6 insect    Coleoptera        59       37.1
```

"Category" is actually a sub-category of "Group", and each "Group" contains distinct "Categories". For example, the algae Group only contains those five different kinds of algae listed in "Category", and the insect group doesn't include any algae categories.

I want the Group to be plotted in a specific order and the number of studies ("studies_n") to be plotted in rank order:

```
Diet$Group <- factor(Diet$Group, levels = c("algae", "detritus", "mollusc", "crustacean", "insect", "fish", "other"))
Diet$Category <- factor(Diet$Category, levels=Diet[order(Diet$studies_n), "Category"])
```

With this established, I have tried two different ways to plot the data:

METHOD A.

```
pDiet <- ggplot(Diet, aes(x=Category, weight=studies_n)) +
  geom_bar() +
  facet_grid(.~Group, scales="free_x", space="free") +
  ylab("number of studies") + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90))  
plot(pDiet)
```

This is ok, but I would rather the bars be horizontal than vertical (to make it easier to read the labels). Also, the text on the x-axis is not aligned.

[image: Plot A]

METHOD B.

```
pDiet <- ggplot(Diet, aes(x=Category, y=studies_n)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank()) +
  facet_grid(Group~., scales="free", space="free") +
  theme(strip.text.y = element_text(angle=0)) +
  ylab("number of studies")
plot(pDiet)
```

This is a better layout, but all of the Categories are plotted for each Group and that's just ridiculous.

[image]

Help?

Comment: Have a look at [the `ggstance` package](https://github.com/lionel-/ggstance) which includes `geom_barh`. This provides a solid way to making these kind of graphs without using `coord_flip` which has a tendency to mess things up.

Comment: it would be good to add your plots from Methods A and B.

Comment: Thanks - added the plots.